# Pandas TimeGrouper: Boundaries for the grouping

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am currently grouping my data by time using

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('AS'))
```

which gives me annual groups. However, I would like these groups to start at March, to be precise `xxxx-03-01` for every year.

One way to enforce this would be to ensure that my first data point is on A March first, or that my last data point ends on February 28th and use `closed='right'`. None of these are feasible for me at the moment. How else could I group annually, from March to March?

Comment: Perhaps a PeriodRange and some slicing instead? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @cphlewis , here is my groupBy method that groups yearly, but starts at a given month:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=25, freq='M')
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng, columns=['ts'])

def groupByYearMonth(ts, month):
    starts = ts[ts.index.month==month].index  # Fix if multiple entries per month.

    if starts[0] > ts.index[0]:
        ts.loc[ts.index < starts[0], 'group'] = starts[0].year - 1
    for start in starts:
        end = '%d-%d'%(start.year+1, start.month-1)
        ts.loc[start:end, 'group'] = start.year
    return ts.groupby('group')

groupBy = groupByYearMonth(ts, 3)
print groupBy.mean(), groupBy.size()
             ts
group          
2010   0.638609
2011  -0.124718
2012   0.385539 group
2010      2
2011     12
2012     11
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Inelegant, but I don't see that groupby has such an argument built in:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=25, freq='M')
ts = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

def truncYears(ts, month):
    starts = ts[ts.index.month==month].index  # Fix if multiple entries per month.

    groups = {}
    if starts[0] > ts.index[0]:
        groups[ts.index[0]] = ts[ts.index < starts[0]]
    for start in starts:
        end = '%d-%d'%(start.year+1, start.month-1)
        print(start, end)
        groups[start] = ts[start:end]

    return groups

groups = truncYears(ts, 3)
for k in groups:
    print(groups[k])
```

result (note dict keys not sorted, so years not in order):

> ```
> 2011-01-31   -1.719806
> 2011-02-28   -0.657064
> Freq: M, dtype: float64
> 2012-03-31    1.200984
> 2012-04-30   -0.496715
> 2012-05-31   -0.998218
> 2012-06-30    1.711504
> 2012-07-31    0.304211
> 2012-08-31    1.091810
> 2012-09-30   -0.716785
> 2012-10-31   -0.996493
> 2012-11-30   -0.541812
> 2012-12-31    1.027787
> 2013-01-31    0.249775
> Freq: M, dtype: float64
> 2011-03-31   -1.406736
> 2011-04-30    0.245077
> 2011-05-31   -0.010090
> 2011-06-30   -1.459824
> 2011-07-31    0.150871
> 2011-08-31   -1.223533
> 2011-09-30    0.859539
> 2011-10-31    0.623674
> 2011-11-30   -2.071204
> 2011-12-31    0.254750
> 2012-01-31    0.667076
> 2012-02-29    0.076249
> Freq: M, dtype: float64
> ```

Comment: I couldn't find anything else either, so I built my final method based on your approach.